# Yii2 run JS-script on error ajax-validation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation, yii2

There is my form:

```
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
      'id' => 'user-create-form',
      'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
      'enableClientValidation' => false,
      'validationUrl' => Url::toRoute(Yii::$app->controller->id . '/validation'),
      'validateOnType' => true,
    ]);
```

JS-script is registered on this form and performed Russian to English transliteration according to some rules on `.keyup()` event. Transliteration result is added to `samname` field.

There is validation rule in `UserCreateForm` model:

```
    public function rules()
    {
      return [
        [['samname'], 'validateUserExist'],
      ];
    }

    public function validateUserExist()
    {
        $check = Yii::$app->CustomComponents->checkUserExist($this->samname);
        if ($check) {
           $errorMessage = 'User exists: ' . $check;
           $this->addError('samname', $errorMessage);
        }
    }
```

Function `checkUserExist()` checks existing of created name and returns an error in matching case.

There is action on controller:

```
    public function actionValidation()
    {
        $model = new UserCreateForm();

        if (\Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            \Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            echo json_encode(ActiveForm::validate($model));
            \Yii::$app->end();
        }
    }
```

It works great, validation is performed, matching case returns an error...

But!

It's required that JS-script is run again and added next letter to the name on error (JS-script provides this functionality). How to run JS-script again after validator was return an error?

Comment: I think it can help you: https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/forms-activeform-js/

Comment: @yafater, I don't understand what event is necessary to use and how exactly use it. Are you help me with?

Comment: How can I help you?

Comment: If I use `afterValidateAttribute` event it returns prevObject with attributes but I can't catch necessary to me item with error. Show an example for me?

Answer (score 0):

@yafater Thanks for help! I find solution.

```
    $('form').on('afterValidateAttribute', function (event, attribute, message) {
        if (attribute.name === 'samname')
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "url-to-action",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                    if ( typeof(response["form-samname"]) != "undefined" && response["form-samname"] !== null ) {
                        // code here
                    }
                },
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
```